# Rest types, JSON or HTML forms with the same URL

Tags: java, jquery, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a RESTful service and encounter a type conflict within the application. Right now, I deal with this problem by using two different URLs, but this leads to other problems and doesn't feel right.

```
// Controller to get a JSON
@RequestMapping(value = "/stuff/{stuffId}",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public stuffDto getStuff(@PathVariable String stuffId) {
    return //JSON DTO//
}

// Controller to get an HTML Form
@RequestMapping(value = "/stuff/{stuffId}/form", // <- nasty '/form' here
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getStuffForm(@PathVariable String stuffId, ModelMap model) {
    // Prepares the model
    return "JSP_Form";
}
```

And on the JavaScript side:

```
function loadStuffForm(url) {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : url,
        success : function(response) {
            showStuffForm(response);
        }
    });
}
```

How can I merge both controllers so it will return the right type of data based on what the client accepts? By default it would return a JSON. I want to add 'text/html' somewhere in the ajax query to get the Form instead. Any idea?

Comment: go through this link... this is what you have been looking for :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110239/multiple-response-types-with-same-rest-get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *Content Negotiation* to communicate to the server and tell it what kind of a response you're expecting form it. In your particular scenario, you as a client using an `Accept` header tell the server to serve a `text/html` or `application/json`. In order to implement this, use two different `produces` with that same URL:

```
// Controller to get a JSON
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/stuff/{stuffId}", method = GET, produces = "application/json")
public stuffDto getStuff( ... ) { ... }

// Controller to get an HTML Form
@RequestMapping(value = "/stuff/{stuffId}", method = GET, produces = "text/html")
public String getStuffForm( ... ) { ... }
```

In your requests to `/stuff/{id}` endpoint, if you send `Accept: text/html` in headers, the HTML form would return. Likewise, you would get the JSON response by sending `Accept: application/json` header.

I'm not a JQuery expert but you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347211/pass-accepts-header-parameter-to-jquery-ajax) out on how to send an `Accept` header in `$.ajax` requests.